# Why does my webpage not display on other computers?

Tags: apache, web, dns, xampp

I am attempting to host a website onto the domain that I purchased from google domains (seanpatnode.com), I have tried several tutorials but I keep getting the same results. Any help would be greatly appreciated! I will give as much information as possible. I am using XAMPP 2.4 as the web server.
Here are relevant lines from my httpd.conf file: (please inform me if I left anything important out.)

```
ServerRoot "C:/xampp/apache"
Listen 80
ServerName localhost:80
<Directory />
AllowOverride none
Require all denied
</Directory>
# DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

These are the relevant lines from my httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/PhpProject"
ServerName seanpatnode.com
ServerAlias www.seanpatnode.com
<Directory "c:/xampp/htdocs/PhpProject">
AllowOverride All
Require all Granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

These are relevant lines from my hosts file located in: C:\WINDOWS\System32\drivers\etc

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   www.seanpatnode.com
```

I can see the webpage when I open www.seanpatnode.com from my own computer. 
However when I try to open it from another computer it says:

> This webpage is not available 
>   The server at www.seanpatnode.com can't 
>   be found, because the DNS lookup failed. DNS is the network service
>   that translates a website's name to its Internet address. This error
>   is most often caused by having no connection to the Internet or a
>   misconfigured network. It can also be caused by an unresponsive DNS
>   server or a firewall preventing Google Chrome from accessing the
>   network.

Again, seanpatnode.com is the domain that I purchased from Google Domains. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's not enough to purchase the domain name, you must also actually put the correct data into it. Specifically in your case, the domain name `www.seanpatnode.com` does not spring into being by itself, you have to create it and make it point at the IP address of your web server.

Comment: I assume that means I need to create a DNS record. Is this what you are talking about? Did I do it correctly? Because I'm not seeing results yet.
[Click here to see image of google domains](http://s18.postimg.org/kygt58xy1/host.png)
I do have a static IP.

I also forwarded my port as well.
[Click for image of port forward](http://s1.postimg.org/omrjtpbsf/ports.png)